# Datatable columndef render not being hit and no error

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, datatable

My goal is every "OUT" or "IN" from database change to the red or green circle but nothing change and no error. 
In column IN and OUT will be contained value "IN" and value "OUT", I want to transform to green circle or red circle.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

View

```
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col" id="IN">IN</th>
            <th scope="col" id="OUT">OUT</th>
            <th scope="col">Comments</th>
```

js

```
    <script>
       $('table').DataTable({
   searching: false, paging: false,
    "ajax": {
        url : "<?php echo site_url("getStatu") ?>",
        type : 'GET', 
             },
        "columnDefs": [
        {
                "data" : "OUT", "orderable" : false,  "defaultContent" : "", 
            "render": function ( data, type, full, meta) {
                  if  (data=="OUT")
                  {    
                                return data ='<i class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:36px; color:red"></i>'

                   } 
            },

        },  ]         
});
```

controller

```
public function getStatu(){

     $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
      $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
      $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));


    $this->load->model('Status_Board_Model');

    $status = $this->Status_Board_Model->getStatu();

   $data = array();

      foreach($status->result() as $r) {

           $data[] = array(
                $r->firstName,
                $r->online,
                $r->offline,
                $r->comment,

           );
      }

      $output = array(
           "draw" => $draw,
             "recordsTotal" => $status->num_rows(),
             "recordsFiltered" => $status->num_rows(),
             "data" => $data
        );
      echo json_encode($output);

}
```

Comment: Where did it send the `draw`, `start`, and `length` input? or is it not made yet? Did the ajax request return the correct data?

Comment: Did my answer not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
public function getStatu(){

 $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
  $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
  $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));


$this->load->model('Status_Board_Model');

$status = $this->Status_Board_Model->getStatu();



$data = array();

  foreach($status->result() as $r) {
    $in = $out = '';
    if($r->online == 'IN'){
    $in = '<i class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:36px; color:green"></i>';
     }
    if($r->offline== 'OUT'){
    $out = '<i class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:36px; color:red"></i>';
     }
       $data[] = array(
            $r->firstName,
            $in,
            $out,
            $r->comment,

       );
  }

  $output = array(
       "draw" => $draw,
         "recordsTotal" => $status->num_rows(),
         "recordsFiltered" => $status->num_rows(),
         "data" => $data
    );
  echo json_encode($output);

}
```

and js:-

```
<script>
   $('table').DataTable({


searching: false, paging: false,
    "ajax": {
        url : "<?php echo site_url("getStatu") ?>",
        type : 'GET', 
             },
        "columnDefs": [
        {
        "render": function ( data, type, full, meta) {
        },

    },  ]         
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that the request returns the correct data, and the `IN` and `OUT` column is the 2nd and 3rd column, you could write it like this :

```
$('table').DataTable({
    searching: false, paging: false,
    "ajax": {
        url : "<?php echo site_url("getStatu") ?>",
        type : 'GET', 
    },
    "columnDefs": [
        { 
            targets: 1,
            data: 1,
            "orderable" : false,
            "defaultContent" : "",
            "render": function ( data, type, full, meta) {
                if  (data=="IN")
                {    
                    data = '<i class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:36px; color:green"></i>'
                }
                return data;
            }
        },
        { 
            targets: 2,
            data: 2,
            "orderable" : false,
            "defaultContent" : "",
            "render": function ( data, type, full, meta) {
                if  (data=="OUT")
                {    
                    data = '<i class="fa fa-circle" style="font-size:36px; color:red"></i>'
                }
                return data;
            }
        }
    ]
});
```